# Definition of cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of linear combinations?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

So a cube is a box, and we can use the usual definition as a product of intervals. (So, by “cube” I don’t just mean the faces of the cube; I also include all the points in its interior.) However, I’m wondering if we can do it in terms of linear combinations. For example, for a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered at the origin with side length $1$, it seems we can define this cube as $\{ a_1 (1/2, 0, 0) + a_2 (0, 1/2, 0) + a_3 (0, 0, 1/2): a_1, a_2, a_3 \in [-1, 1] \}$.

More generally, can we define a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin with side length $s$ as the set $$\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \frac{s}{2} e_i: |a_i| \leq 1 \}, $$ where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector?

One reason I am asking is because I feel it may sometimes be easier to work with this definition than the definition of boxes as a product of intervals, especially if we don’t really care about whether it’s a box or a cube. For example, one thing we can show is that every cube centered at the origin (call this a cube at $0$) is contained in a ball centered at the origin (call this a ball at $0$), and vice versa: Given a cube at $0$, just choose a ball at $0$ with radius greater than the distance of one of the cube’s vertices to the origin (I think this is given by $\sqrt{n(\frac{s}{2})^2}$). Conversely, given a ball at $0$, just choose a cube at $0$ whose side length equals the radius of the ball.

From this result it follows that all balls are contained in boxes, and vice versa, as follows: Every box is clearly contained in some cube at $0$, hence in some ball at $0$, which is a ball; and conversely, every ball is contained in some ball at $0$, hence in some cube at $0$, which is a box.

Another intuitive reason I have is that working with linear combinations might be nice, e.g. we can take linear transformations and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definition is not truly a *linear combination* because the coordinates are constrained.

You can use a more classical *convex combination*

$$p=\sum \lambda_k c_k,$$ where $\sum \lambda_k=1$ and $\lambda_k\ge0$. The $c_k$ are the eight corners.

Comment: Ok, since you require $\lambda_k \geq 0$, I assume you are talking about the cube one of whose vertices is the origin? So, it would just be a translation of the cube centered at the origin, which was what I originally considered?

Comment: "I assume you are talking about the cube one of whose vertices is the origin": no, I am not. The corners can be anywhere, even rotated or stretched.

Comment: Oh... I see. After looking "convex combination" up, I assume this follows because the "convex hull" is given as the set of all convex combinations? That is a lot more general and elegant, thanks!

Comment: @twosigma: that's right, you are getting the convex hull of the points.